# Rails 4: Additional form field

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, tags, slim-lang

That is how my new/edit message form looks like (I'm using [slim](http://slim-lang.com/)):

```
= form_for(@message) do |f|
  = f.label :message
  br
  = f.text_area :content
  br
  = f.submit 'Submit'
```

Is there a way to send additional field through form (Which is not defined in any model?). I want to use it in 'create' method inside messages controller.

Comment: It would really help if you could post a **minimal** example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: I reduced it to basic problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using Rails 4 you can create a custom accessor in the model:

`attr_accessor :content`

and it will not be saved to database.

In Rails 5 there's a specific macro about that that can also typecast the attribute for reading.

Anyway, ensure that the attribute is also on the list of whitelisted parameters if using http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Answer (score 2):

You can create and submit arbitrary fields using the [`hidden_field`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field) method:

```
= f.hidden_field(:name)
```

This presumes you have a model field. If not you use `hidden_field_tag`:

```
= hidden_field_tag(:name, 'value')
```